# Saving NSDictionary to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a NSMutableDictionary, and i have added values to it (several key pair values). Now i require to save this NSMutableDictionary to a NSUserDefaults object.

1.) My code as follows; I am not sure if it is correct , and also i need to know how to retrieve the NSMutableDictionary from the NSUSerDefault ?

2.) After retrieving the NSMutableDictionary i need to save it to a NSDictionary. How could i do these ?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];

[dic addObject:@"sss" forKey:@"hi"];
[dic addObject:@"eee" forKey:@"hr"];

 [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"DicKey"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: You also need to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];` to save.  What exactly are you struggling with?  You've mentioned what you want to do but not where you are having problems.  The code you've included above (aside from a missing `[`) looks fine.

Comment: I need to save some key-value pairs and access it from a different view. So i thought of using NSUserDefaults for this and also NSDictionary. Finally i will have to populate a table with these values.

Comment: Unless you add more detail, I doubt you will get more answers.  You're setting things just fine.  Are you not finding the dictionary when you call `[[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"DicKey"]`?  Note that this will be a `NSDictionary*` type and NOT a `NSMutableDictionary*`.  If you want to manipulate data across views, consider storing the data in a data model that you pass to both views (or provide a singleton accessor on it depending on how generic / visible you want the data to be).

Comment: It is not recommended to save to user defaults for access it from another view. You could either send as parameter, or use singleton

Comment: Note that the use of 'synchronize' isn't needed anymore: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc

Answer (score 88):

Your code is correct, but the one thing you have to keep in mind is that `NSUserDefaults` doesn't distinguish between mutable and immutable objects, so when you get it back it'll be immutable:

```
NSDictionary *retrievedDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"DicKey"];
```

If you want a mutable dictionary, just use `mutableCopy`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableRetrievedDictionary = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DicKey"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Remember that, using `copy` you are retaining the object, so you'll become the owner and you'll be responsible to release it.

Comment: I am using ARC. And, I need to save a NSMutableDictionary to NSUser Defaults, and get a NSDictionary from a NSUserDefaults. So i have to use your 1st approach i guess ?

Comment: Whoops, needed to do `mutableCopy` instead of `copy` to get a mutable dictionary. But yeah, for what you describe, you want the first version.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSMutableDictionary *profileDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
[profileDictionary setObject:txt_Username.text forKey:@"USERNAME_KEY"];
[profileDictionary setObject:txt_Password forKey:@"PASSWORD_KEY"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:profileDictionary forKey:@"PROFILE_KEY"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This is what you expected.